# Which tool used to uglify this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

While checking source code of a page I saw the JS code uglified as seen here:

```
eval((function(D28){for(var J28="",p28=0,C28=function(D28,y28){for(var L28=0,E28=0;E28=32&&t28<=127){L28+=t28-32;}}return L28;};p28((0x50,48.)>(54.0E1,99.)?2:1.3860E3<=(27.,0xA9)?(1.95E2,0x229):13.98E2<(126,0x240)?2:(0x1B2,0x19F)>(0x9F,105)?(140.,0):(104.,0xF3)<=99?\"W\"` Q 6E,19))){I=X.substring(v,Q);c=I.length;return Y(I,c,x);}else if(v===((13.25E2,77.)>=(0x157,146.)?(26.,70.9E1):(0x213,10.59E2)<` F 6,9.02E2)?(0x5,\"r\"):(52,18.3E1)>(1.137E3,82.)?(0.,null):(25.8E1,19.5E1)>=(0x1E5,0x183)?(9.4E1,\'r\'):(11.84E2,7` N )<0x196?0:(84,82.))||v<=(7.92E2>=(0xCD,1.062E3)?8.73E2:119.>=(14.9E1,12)?(135,0):(0x55,100.)>(55.,102.)?(0x255,46.` > 253,31)>=(0xD4,4.10E1)?0x1D4:(0xB8,140.)>9.68E2?(1.24E3,0xA2):(131.,0x115))){I=X.substring(((0x171,81.2E1)>65.10E1?(4.11E2,0):(146,0xA6)<(143.,99.)?0x241:(0x247,0x1D6)>=(0x222,10.96E2)?4.86E2:(1.0E1,0x130)<0xB6?(0x1C1,127.10E1):(0x164,2.23E2)<=29?(52.80E1,136.):(14.46E2,11.03E2)),X.length);c=I` %\";return Y(I,c,x);}I=X.substring(` L#-v` 8B,d=function(v,x){var Q=x&((0x146,71.7E1)<
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jxzpxgv/show/

Do you guys have any idea which tool is used? I don't think this is UglifyJS, Closure or YUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's JavaScript Obfuscator, you can "encrypt" you source code to make more difficult for humans to understand. There are a lot of tools of this kind on the internet. Here is one of them: https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Comment: This was quick really. Thanks.